# Call child class contructor from parent class parametrized constructor from child class parametrized constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, virtual

So I have a Parent Class and a child Class inherited from it. Parent class has a default and parametrized constructor. Child class has slightly different default constructor, but exactly same code in parametrized constructor. It looks like this:

```
class Parent{
    public String A;
    public int B;

    public Parent(){
        A = "parent";
        B = 0;
    }

    public Parent(int v){
        this();
        B = v;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{

    public Child(){
        A = "child";
        B = 0;
    }

    public Child(int v){
        this();
        B = v;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Child c = new Child(5);
    System.out.println("A: "+c.A); // > A: child
}
```

Now this works all fine and dandy, but boring. If I replace the `Child(int v){}` with following:

```
public Child(int v){
    super(v);
}
```

I save 1 line and it's more fun, but apparently `super(v)` calls Parent's `this()` inside.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Child c = new Child(5);
    System.out.println("A: "+c.A); // > A: parent
}
```

Is it possible to make `super()` call the Child's `this()`?

I know I can do a `Class(){this(0)}` , but that is no fun.

I imagine you can do something like that by playing around with `virtual` keyword in C++ maybe? Anyway, what do you think?

Comment: Are you asking how to produce c++ code that behaves like the java code you show? It's not clear to me what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Calling `virtual` member functions from a constructor will not work the way you expect. It will not be polymorphic. When constructing the parent portion, the child portion hasn't begun existing yet. It would be unreasonable to call it's implementation of virtual member functions. For the same reason, it's unreasonable to try to call a child type's constructor from a parent type's constructor.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I thought the c++ tag was incorrect as well, but then if you read the last line of the question it looks like all of that java code is just a way to express the intended behavior and the question is actually asking about c++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I thought that too, for a second. But if you re-read that last line it doesn't make much sense in the question, unless the meant "like you do by playing around with `virtual` keyword in C++ maybe?". Still, if you think the tag should be there, feel free to re-add it, I won't change it this time :)

Comment: I was wondering if it can be done in either cpp or java. I now see my folly. I was sure, that virtual constructors would work (after all if I don't call `super` at all, it still constructs the child, so i thought maybe super calls constructor as an ordinary function or smth.